# Use of unresolved identifier 'dispatch_get_main_queue' using SWIFT

Tags: macos, swift

I am having difficulty using 'dispatch_get_main_queue()' in SWIFT with the base SDK set to 10.9. The code that I am using is a simple dispatch_async call shown below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        // Code here
}
```

However it is generating the error: Use of unresolved identifier 'dispatch_get_main_queue'. It works as expected when the base SDK is set to 10.10, but not at 10.9. I use it in objective-c in non-swift applications which use the base SDK 10.9 but I cannot figure out why it is not working with Swift.

I have tried to look into it but have currently been unable to find anything about why this is happening and what I can do to resolve it/achieve similar functionality. I would be very grateful if anyone can shed any light on this or point me in the right direction.

So my question is: Is there a way I can resolve this (or at least achieve similar functionality)?

EDIT 1 -

This is the full function I have created:

```
func addSubview(aView: NSView, fillView: Bool, removeExisting: Bool)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

        if (aView != nil)
        {
            if (removeExisting)
            {
                for (var subview: NSView) in self.subviews() as NSView[]
                {
                    subview.removeFromSuperview();
                }
            }

            if (fillView)
            {
                aView.setAutoresizingMask(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable);
                aView.setFrame(NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.frame().size.width, self.frame().size.height));
            }

            self.addSubview(aView);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 - Replaced 'if (aView != null)' to 'if (aView != nil)' as suggested. I am not sure how I managed to make that rookie error!

Comment: Where do you use it? In your Appdelegate or?

Comment: I have tried using it in both the AppDelegate and my own custom class that is a subclass of NSView.

Comment: My guess is that in the 10.10 SDK, many definitions were updated to be "Swift compatible". So you probably *have* to use that SDK, and only set the deployment version to 10.9.

Comment: I have usually set the Base SDK to the same as the Deployment Target, but I will definitely look further into doing this. I see how this could be an issue with Swift and using an older SDK. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use it in a function. This should work:

```
func test() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    }
}
```

Works fine on my laptop with deployment target 10.9

Or in your app delegate maybe something like this:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    }
}
```

First you should replace `if (aView != null)` to `if (aView != nil)`
Swift uses `nil` not `null`

Comment: Hello, I am currently trying to use it in a custom function that I have made but with no luck. Have you also set the Base SDK to 10.9? I have both deployment target and base SDK set to 10.9.

Comment: Yes both are set to 10.9. Maybe the problem is in your custom function. You can add your custom function to your question so I can try to help you further.

Comment: Added! Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

If view can be nil you should use optional type:

```
func addSubview(view: NSView?, fillView: Bool, removeExisting: Bool) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        if let aView = view {
            if removeExisting {
                ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I will be sure to implement like this from now on.